Automatic proofs concerning inequalities
I've heard that Isabelle can be used to get automatic answers to questions like this:
lemma "∃ x :: real . 2 /3 < x ∧ x < 3 /4"
Of course, this one can be easily proved by hand, but I wanted to illustrate a simplest example that I can't do by automation.
The report I get from Sledgehammer is:
vc4 found a proof...  cvc4 found a proof...  cvc4: One-line proof reconstruction failed: by (smt (verit) comm_semiring_class.distrib field_class.field_divide_inverse field_class.field_inverse mult.commute)  cvc4: Duplicate proof  cvc4 found a proof...  cvc4: Duplicate proof  Done
Any ideas?

This sounds like a bug. Is that what you're asking?

@cody is there a different way to do it that gets around the "bug" perhaps?

What's going on?
Oftentimes, sledgehammer comes up with proof ideas that cannot be replayed in Isabelle/HOL. This is the case here, as indicated by

One-line proof reconstruction failed

It's virtually impossible to tell for a particular case why something like this happens. Still, the output sometimes conveys tips (here: which lemmas were sufficient to prove the claim in cvc4). Also, that some tool has found a proof usually means that one can also find one in Isabelle/HOL—so it's at least reassuring in cases where one is unsure whether one has the right claim.
How to prove it with automatic tools
Sometimes it can be a strategy to first use the magic of Isabelle's automatic tools like safe or simp to normalize the goal into a more machine-friendly form. For me, the following works in Isabelle/HOL 2024:
lemma ‹∃x::real. 2 / 3 < x ∧ x < 3 / 4›
  apply simp
  (* proof sate: ∃x. 2 < x * 3 ∧ x * 4 < 3 *)
  by (smt (z3))

It's a bit of alchemy. What is particularly dangerous about this approach is that such proofs might break if you change something about the simp-ruleset in your theory. (More so, if the final smt-call were to use a lot of specific sledgehammered facts, which might fail on a slightly changed claim.)
Generally, it's better to avoid simp-then-sledgehammer situations. But given that the question was specifically about automatic tools, this proof shows that they can get the job done.
Maintainable proofs
When one is aware of an easy “by-hand” proof, I would advise to encode it in the Isabelle proof script. The merit in this is that the proof script can be more easily maintained when refactoring the theory later on. (When working on a theory with several people or over a longer period, one tends to forget, why a specific step was “easy to see”.)
So, when proving an existence, it's best for automatic tools and humans alike if the author explicitly constructs a witness. In the example, this would be:
lemma ‹∃x::real. 2 / 3 < x ∧ x < 3 / 4›
proof -
  have ‹(2::real) / 3 < 17 / 24› by simp (* by arith would also work*)
  moreover have ‹(17::real) / 24 < 3 / 4› by simp
  ultimately show ?thesis by blast
qed

Another option: Learning from the simplifier
Coming back to the simplifier approach. We can learn which rules the simplifier used to massage the goal by writing
declare [[simp_trace]]

somewhere at the top of our theory. In this instance, it tells us that the simplifier used the facts Num.divide_less_eq_numeral1(1) and Num.less_divide_eq_numeral1(1) as rewrite rules to get rid of the divisions. We can perform this rewriting by hand using unfolding, obtaining the following proof alternative:
lemma ‹∃x::real. 2 / 3 < x ∧ x < 3 / 4›
  unfolding Num.divide_less_eq_numeral1(1) Num.less_divide_eq_numeral1(1)
  by smt


Thanks! In Lean we can write simp? to see what simp did, us there something like that in Isabelle?

You can write declare [[simp_trace]] somewhere above the lemma. In this instance, it tells me that the simplifier used rewrite rules Num.divide_less_eq_numeral1_1 and Num.less_divide_eq_numeral1_1 (which can be traced back to facts if one drops the _1...)

@BjørnKjos-Hanssen I've added the entailed proof idea to the answer. Thanks!
